# How do I setDate with Ajax using Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datepicker

I'm updating a JQuery datepicker with Ajax and have to reinitialize the datepicker each time, but the date is automatically set to the current date rather than the selected date. How do I change my code to pass the correct date?

I'm currently trying to use a Rails method like (params[:start_time].to_datetime).month for the year/month/day, but I keep getting errors when I apply it to new Date()

Index.js

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker(
{
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
onSelect: function(dateText) {
    $.getScript(document.location.href + '&start_time=' + dateText, function(data) {
    });
}
});
$('#datepicker3').datepicker("setDate", new Date(2008,9,03) );
```

Comment: I don't really understand. Is this your javascript template? Shouldn't it be a .js.erb file? Where's the embedded ruby?

Comment: Yeah it's a js.erb file used when the index controller action is called remotely. The ruby I've experimented with would be $('#datepicker3').datepicker("setDate", new Date(<%= (params[:start_time].to_datetime).year %>, <%= (params[:start_time].to_datetime).month %>, <%= (params[:start_time].to_datetime).day %>) );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, your problem seems to be converting date formats from a string to a ruby object, then to a javascript object.

Try doing something like this:

```
<% date = Time.strptime(params[:start_time], "%y-%m-%d").to_i * 1000 %>
$('#datepicker3').datepicker("setDate", new Date(<%= date %>) );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work if you set input value before calling .datepicker, ex:

```
= f.text_field :some_date, :type => 'date', :value => @some_date
```

and then in your js:

```
$(":date").datepicker();
```